# Find Subdocument in Array with mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I am playing around with the The bios Example Collection from http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/bios-example-collection to educate myself about querying mongodb.

I want to retrieve informations about the awards won by **_id : 1** in **year : 1975**.

I tried several queries, among those

```
bios.find({
    "_id" : 1,
    "awards" : {
        "year" : 1975
    }
});
```

but I never receive the proper document back. How can I retrieve this document in the array?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You have to use the [dot notation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation):

```
bios.find({"_id" : 1, "awards.year" : 1975 });
```

It's a rather pointless query, because you also have the `_id` in the query, but I guess that's due to the fact that you're playing with an example. Also, you're saying you're looking for awards from 1967, but the code says 1975.

If you search for `"awards" : { "year" : 1975 }`, mongodb will look for an exact match of the entire subdocument `awards`. In this case, that is not what you want. Also, since `awards` is an array, this will always be false. If you wanted to look up a specific award document in a list, [`$elemMatch`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) would be the way to go.

Comment: The year was a typo. Thanks very much for the detailled explanation!